# Why can't I read my transaction log backup file using fn_dump_dblog?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, transaction-log, restore

I'm using [this blog](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/) on sqlskills.com as a guide to practice finding the relevant LSN in a transaction log backup for point in time recovery.

After backing up the transaction log, I attempt to read it with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fn_dump_dblog (
NULL, NULL, 'DISK', 1, 'D:\TEMP\test_tlog2.bak',
DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 615, Level 21, State 1, Line 1
>   Could not find database ID 0, name '0'. The database may be offline. Wait a few minutes and try again.

The database id isn't 0, it isn't offline, I don't see any params I'm missing or changes to the function. I can query the database and I can view the tlog backup file from within SSMS backup using the contents option, shows correct media set 1.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4263.0 (X64)   Aug 23 2012 15:56:56   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: I have the same issue running 2008R2 10.50.4000.

Comment: Unless you are doing it for educational purpose (it is undocumented), Paul has a bold caution - **Jonathan just found out from a customer system that uses this extensively that every time fn_dump_dblog is called, it creates a new hidden SQLOS scheduler and up to three threads, which will not go away (and will not be reused) until a server restart.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Alan Please check once by disabling the audit.

> That server has an AUDIT on a database. If the audit is enabled, you
>   will get that error.  If you disable the audit,query will run fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Karthick, do you know why audit causes this? Is this documented aywhere? I was having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the steps as explained [here](http://janiceclee.wordpress.com/tag/fn_dump_dblog/). On the other hand, there is a SQL Server auditing tool [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) that can help you in finding the relevant LSN via GUI and without T-SQL use

Disclaimer: I work as a Product Support Engineer at ApexSQL