# SQL Server Troubleshooting Replication and Long-Running fn_dblog query

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, transaction-log, transactional-replication

I am trying to get (pull) Transactional Replication working again for a subscriber.

Currently, in Replication Monitor I am seeing messages in the Publisher to Distributor tab and the Distributor to Subscriber tab.

In the distributor to subscriber history, I see 'concurrent snapshot for publication 'XX' not available'. In the publisher to distributor history, I see the Log Reader Agent initializing and then waiting for a response from the server (every 5 minutes the message is logged again).

Ultimately the execution of `sp_replcmds` fails.

I think there may be many unreplicated transactions which are causing the Log Reader Agent to hang. Following [Troubleshooting LogReader Timeouts](https://web.archive.org/web/20150812225404/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/repltalk/archive/2010/10/25/troubleshooting-logreader-timeout-executing-sp-replcmds.aspx)

I ran `dbcc opentran` and then attempted to run

```
select  [Transaction ID], count([Transaction ID]) as 'Count log entries'
from::fn_dblog('42006:31381:2',null) 
where [Description] = 'REPLICATE'
group by [Transaction ID]
```

This query did not return any results after over 40 minutes. Moreover, when I just run `SELECT count(*) FROM ::fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)` I am not getting results after a long time (20 minutes).

I am starting to think there is something up with the size of my transaction log, or some kind of corruption, or something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many VLFs do you have in that log file? You can use DBCC LOGINFO to get a row per VLF. What's the count?

Comment: `DBCC LOGINFO` returns 411 rows.

Comment: The Replication Monitor has a screen where it shows the number of unreplicated commands. Can you find the number from there? (Sorry, I don't have the exact steps in front of me right now.) Also, is the transaction log file a reasonable size, or is it really large?

Comment: The transaction log is 932624 pages. There are 0 unreplicated commands on the Undistributed Commands tab.
I am inclined to delete and re-create the publication at this point.

Answer (score 1):

If fn_dblog is hanging you may try some third party tools from ApexSQL, RedGate or Idera. Or you can try to backup the transaction log file and use fn_dump_dblog just to exclude problems with an online transaction log. You can find more info on this [DBA post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51994/28609)

Comment: Note that `fn*log` is undocumented. Paul has a bold caution - [Jonathan just found out from a customer system that uses this extensively that every time fn_dump_dblog is called, it creates a new hidden SQLOS scheduler and up to three threads, which will not go away (and will not be reused) until a server restart](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/).